# Interrupt Document with Ancillary Material

Tags: output-routine

Suppose I want to create an in-class text.  Suppose further that as a lecturer I want *my* copy of the text to have copious amounts of ancillary material (notes, solutions to exercises, blackboard examples, etc.) included.  The mass of additional material won't fit comfortably in the margins, so what I'd want to do is have additional insert pages that appear at the end of each section, such that if I removed them from my version of the text the resulting pages would be identical to the students' version (so that the page numbers correspond exactly).

Here's a minimum working example that simply adds or removes material in an `ancillary` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\newif\ifshowancil \showanciltrue

\ifshowancil
\newenvironment{ancillary}%
    {\itshape
    \newpage
    %And other stuff...
    }%
    {\newpage
    %And other stuff...
    }
\else
\newenvironment{ancillary}{\comment}{}
\fi

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20]

\begin{ancillary}
\textbf{Here is the beginning.}
\lipsum[21-30] 
\textbf{And the end.}
\end{ancillary}

\lipsum[31-40]

\end{document}
```

What I would like is for the `anciltrue` version to compile identical to the `ancilfalse` version, but with the stuff in the `ancillary` environment typeset independently of the rest of the document, beginning on the next page (like a float), with "temporary'' page numbering (e.g. 30a, 30b, etc. if it follows page 30).

Is such a scheme possible without too much labor?  I'm thinking a solution would require tinkering with the output routine, hence the tag.

Comment: I don't think you need to explicitly change the output routine. Just e.g. use `afterpage` or something and `pageslts`.

Comment: If you don't want to print the ancil content then use `\color{white}` inside that environment when the boolean is false, so that the pagination does not change.

Comment: @cfr I had no idea about `afterpage`.  I must investigate further...

Comment: @Jagath Those pages shouldn't be printed at all, so my solution requires the extra pages to appear as an even number of "full-page floats" that will pause the normal text's page numbering.

Comment: Floats cannot include page breaks. So to use floats, you'd have to chunk the material into page-sized bits. But `afterpage` might allow you to do without this, though I'm not certain.

Comment: @cfr Sorry, I meant float-like behavior in that it inserts itself at the next page break, not that it would be a proper float.  `afterpage` is showing lots of promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{afterpage,environ,pageslts,fancyhdr}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \pagenumbering{arabic}%
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhf[cf]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{fancil}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhf[cf]{\arabic{savepage}(\thepage)}%
}
\newcounter{savepage}

\newif\ifshowancil \showanciltrue
% \showancilfalse

\ifshowancil
  \newcommand\saveancil{}%
  \environbodyname\envancil
  \NewEnviron{ancillary}%
  {%
    \global\let\saveancil\envancil
    \setcounter{savepage}{\thepage}%
    \afterpage{%
      \pagenumbering{roman}%
      \pagestyle{fancil}%
      \itshape
      \saveancil
      \newpage
      \pagenumbering{arabic}%
      \pagestyle{fancy}%
    }%
  }
\else
  \NewEnviron{ancillary}{}{}
\fi

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20]

\begin{ancillary}
\textbf{Here is the beginning.}
\lipsum[21-30]
\textbf{And the end.}
\end{ancillary}

\lipsum[31-40]

\end{document}
```

[image: ancillary]